# SDWebImage implementation in parse using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I am using parse to retrieve my images and labels and display it on a collection view. The problem was that the collection view loads all the images and labels at once making the load time long and memory usage was high.  I was thinking that I would load 10 cells each time however I was recommended to use SDWebImage to make the app lighter. However I don't know how to implement it with parse using swift.  I am suspecting that I would put some code in this piece of code below

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("newview", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewCollectionViewCell
    let item = self.votes[indexPath.row]


    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("onDoubleTap:"))
    gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)


    // Display "initial" flag image
    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
    cell.postsImageView.image = initialThumbnail

    // Display the country name
    if let user = item["uploader"] as? PFUser{
        item.fetchIfNeeded()
        cell.userName!.text = user.username


        var profileImgFile = user["profilePicture"] as! PFFile
        cell.profileImageView.file = profileImgFile
        cell.profileImageView.loadInBackground { image, error in
            if error == nil {
                cell.profileImageView.image = image
            }
        }

        var sexInt = user["sex"] as! Int
        var sex: NSString!
        if sexInt == 0 {
            sex = "M"
        }else if sexInt == 1{
            sex = "F"
        }

        var height = user["height"] as! Int
        cell.heightSexLabel.text = "\(sex) \(height)cm"



    }

    if let votesValue = item["votes"] as? Int
    {
        cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(votesValue)"
    }

    // Fetch final flag image - if it exists
    if let value = item["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
        println("Value \(value)") 
        cell.postsImageView.file = value
        cell.postsImageView.loadInBackground({ (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                cell.postsImageView.image = image
            }
        })
    }

    return cell
}
```

I have implemented SDWebImage using Pods and have imported through the Bridging Header. Is there anyone who knows how to implement SDWebImage with parse using Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rethink your approach -

I believe you are using collectionViewDelegate method - `collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)`

this fires every time the collection view needs a view to handle.

In there you can access the cell imageView and set its image (For Example)-

```
cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage:placeHolderImage, completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) -> Void in  })
```

And if you wish to fade in the image nicely, you could -

```
cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage:placeHolderImage, completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) -> Void in
            if (cacheType == SDImageCacheType.None && image != nil) {
                imageView.alpha = 0;
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.0, animations: { () -> Void in
                    imageView.alpha = 1
                })
            } else {
                imageView.alpha = 1;
            }
        })
```

**EDIT**

I see the you use Parse, so you don't need SDWebImage, you need to use Parse -  [PFImageView](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#user-interface-pfimageview), It will handle your background fetch for the image when it loads. You will need to save reference to your PFObject, but I believe you already do that.

For example (inside your cellForItemAtIndexPath)-

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]; // placeholder image
imageView.file = (PFFile *)someObject[@"picture"]; // remote image

[imageView loadInBackground];
```

Comment: Yes I am using collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:) and I Know how to set image. I have it fully working but the load time is too long and frustrating since it loads everything at once

Comment: Please explain your self. As cellForItemAtIndexPath should be called only for visible cells. Are you sure the collection view loads all the cells at once ?

Comment: yes.. but I don't need fancy animations please reread my question. I could show my cellForItemAtIndexPath if asked

Comment: Added an EDIT to my answer

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question and added more code, is this ok?

Comment: yes its working completely find just finding a way to make it so that it loads 10 at a time. Like when it scrolls down another set of 10 cells are loaded

Comment: @shannoga - incidentally, the OP could have used SDWebImage, but would have had to (1) realize the PFFile answers the url and (2) result ought to be cached to avoid running over and over.  OP also apparently didn't realize that PFFile loadInBackground produces NSData, not UIImage.  UIImage can be constructed with the NSData (varieties of imageWithData).

Answer (score 0):

How many objects are displaying in the collection view? 
Since you mentioned `SDWebImage`, are you downloading the images in the background as well?

If you want to load the images as the user scrolls, have a look at the documentation for `SDWebImage`. The [first use case](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-uiimageviewwebcache-category-with-uitableview) describes how to display images in table view cells withouth blocking the main thread. The implementation for collection view cells should be similar.

Comment: Yes thank you I have read it but I don't know what to replace for sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage: method  since Parse has no URL

Comment: So how do you get the images from Parse?

Comment: cell.postsImageView.loadInBackground({ (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void in  I am loading in Background

Comment: Seems there is no need for `SDWebImage` then, Parse is doing something similar. Run your app in instruments using the Time Profile and check what is slowing down the collection view.

Comment: Really !! However why is it loading slow, is there anyway so that I can make it so that it won't load at once and load 10 at a time or so